# Suddenly unable to write and delete files in external harddrive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, I upgraded from 17.10. I dual-boot with Windows 10. I have a hard drive that I formatted ntfs to store files so I can access  through windows or ubuntu. It worked well until today when I tried to delete a file and all of a sudden I found that I did not have the permissions. I am unable to delete files, or make any changes to the files on the hard drive. I also cannot change the permissions on the hard drive.

Comment: Can someone help with this?

Comment: Did you try booting with Windows and see if from there you can access the file system and do a partition check?

Answer (score 1):

not really a solution, but this tends to happen to me when windows doesn't shut down properly, eg. freezes and I have to force restart. booting windows and restarting properly usually solves it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and forgot to come back here and say so. What happened was that somehow the mounting option settings got changed. Under Identify as, I had it under label which I named my hdd as Volume. That got changed somehow and that was the cause of my issues. As soon as I changed it back to Identify as label, it all got resolved. Thank you for getting back to me, I should not be so impatient.